# ggplot2: Point sizes increasing towards more negative values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using scale_size() to change the size of points (created with geom_point()) in accordance with a continuous variable.

```
ggplot(data,
       aes(x = cat_var,
           y = cont_var1)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = cont_var2)) +
  scale_size()
```

However, this continuous variable contains both negative and positive values, and by default increases the size of points towards the higher positive values:

[image]

I would like to know whether there is an option in scale_size() (I can not find it in the documentation), or another similar function, that can invert this ordering and increase point sizes towards high negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(data,
       aes(x = cat_var,
           y = cont_var1)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = cont_var2)) +
  scale_size(range=c(12,2))
```

Change the range to be diminishing like this should swap I believe.